# Underflow on transparent fixed header

Tags: html, css

I have built a page with a fixed header that always stays on top of the page. The page has a background picture and the header is transparent.

My basic layout:

```
<div id="header-container">

    <header class="wrapper">
        <h1 id="title">Headline</h1>
    </header>
    <nav id="main-navigation" class="wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Nav Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav> <!-- #main-navigation -->

</div> <!-- #header-container -->

<div id="main-container" class="wrapper">

    <article id="main">    
            <section class="content">
                <h2>some headline</h2>
                <p>content stuff</p>
            </section>
    </article> <!-- #main -->


    <footer id="footer">
            footer stuff
    </footer><!-- #footer -->

</div> <!-- #main-container -->​
```

And this is the most important css:

```
#main-container {
    margin-top: 150px;
}    

#header-container{
    height: 150px;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
}
```

Here my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0xsven/RBnHt/

When I scroll the site down I want the #main-container's underflow (below the header-container) to be hidden (somehow like a reversed overflow:hidden).

How do I accomplish that without changing too much on the layout side?

Comment: for that you have to use javascript

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the transparent header.

If it's transparent, then you will see the body stuff scrolling inside it...

The background image is for the whole document, not just the header.

You should really split your image, with a 150px image for the header, and an image without the first 150px for the rest.

Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/tTjVe/1/

```
#header-container{
    ...
    ...
    background: url("http://www.webdesign.org/img_articles/20024/110.jpg") no-repeat top center fixed;
    background-size: 100% 150px;
}
```

The fiddle is using your same entire background image for the header and the body too... just split it in two and you will be alright.

Comment: Actually my solution was to give the header and the html document the same image, which worked fine. But as soon as I want to change the background with some jquery slider plugin it gets messy... Was hoping for cleaner solution. Thank you for your answer.